# Modify sent amount on Transfer hook

Tags: token-2022, transfer-checked

I have been recently started to play around the transfer hook and explored the Anchor tutorial on the website.
My question is **if the transfer hook reflects the end state of the transfer is there any way to alter that amount without requiring a delegate from the receiver?**

Example: I want to implement a custom tax token, with a progressive transfer fee depending on the user current balance that works out of the box with current swaps, in my mind i would need to check the transferred amount on my hook and dynamically split it (e.g. 95% - 5%), is there an intended way to do that without having to prepare that split beforehand and transferring only the supposed 95% and then taking the extra 5% using a signer delegate?

I hope the question is clear, thank you very much for the support!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't be possible with a transfer hook.

Remember that only a program that owns an account can modify its contents. In the case of token-2022, this means that only token-2022 can modify the balances of its accounts.

A transfer hook, being a separate program, will not be able to modify those balances, so it's not possible to change the transfer amount in a transfer hook.

If you want to take a fee denominated in the same token type, you'll need to use the "transfer fee" extension: https://spl.solana.com/token-2022/extensions#transfer-fees -- this wouldn't be a progressive fee, but you can create an off-chain worker that periodically collects fees and rebates a certain amount to users.